# e1071 R library error when dataframe contains categorical values

Tags: r, svm

I am working with a dataframe that contains categorical values in two columns. To use the svm function under e1071 , I converted the columns into factors and currently the structure of my data frame is as follows.

```
'data.frame':   101 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Sequence_length: num  795 795 795 613 613 613 739 739 739 508 ...
 $ FAW            : num  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ farc           : Factor w/ 30 levels "Aegerolysin",..: 12 12 12 15 15 15 13 13 13 4 ...
 $ ffolds         : Factor w/ 8 levels "a/b barrels",..: 7 5 3 7 5 3 7 5 3 2 ...
```

I ran the svm function on this dataframe and it gives me the following error:

```
Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Please help me in understanding the error and my hope was changing the categorical columns to factor would take care of the data format for running the svm. What should I do to get this working ?

Data example:

```
Endo_N+Endo_M+Endo_C 795  1 beta sandwiches

Endo_N+Endo_M+Endo_C    795 1   beta duplicates or obligate multimers

Endo_N+Endo_M+Endo_C    795 1   alpha arrays

Endo_N+Endo_mid+Endo_mid    613 1   beta sandwiches

Endo_N+Endo_mid+Endo_mid    613 0   beta duplicates or obligate multimers
```

Sorry for the format of the table.
Thank you.

Comment: _how_ did you run `svm`

Comment: As rawr points out, this question would be **much better** if you gave the explicit call you used.

Comment: **svm_model<- svm(y=labels,x=mydata)**                                         str(labels)
num [1:101] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

Comment: labels is a vector with my class values